# Apache SOLR edisMAX, Multiple keywords and sequence of those keywords yielding different results

Tags: solr

I am trying to understand the root cause of an issue with my SOLR search query.  Below code is SOLRJ client code.

```
query.setStart(0);
query.setRows(1000);
query.set("debugQuery", true);
query.set("defType", "edismax");
query.setQuery("title:business OR statistics) OR (name:business OR statistics)");           
query.add("fq", "bsuiness_id:(101 102)");
query.add("tie", "0.1");
query.set("bq","weight:[0 TO 500]^1 weight:[501 TO 1000]^3");
```

**returns 200 search results**

```
query.setStart(0);
query.setRows(1000);
query.set("debugQuery", true);
query.set("defType", "edismax");
query.setQuery("title:statistics OR business) OR (name:statistics OR business)");           
query.add("fq", "bsuiness_id:(101 102)");
query.add("tie", "0.1");
query.set("bq","weight:[0 TO 500]^1 weight:[501 TO 1000]^3");
```

**returns 100 search results**

My understanding is keyword "business statistics" and "statistics business" should yield same results.  However, you may notice above that they are not.

Can someone please provide any pointers about what is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries are not the same. (And you're missing a `(` at the start)

```
title:business OR statistics) OR (name:business OR statistics)
```

searches for `business` in the `title` field and `statistics` in the default search field (since it doesn't seem like you have a `qf` parameter), or `business` in the `name` field and again, `statistics` in the default search field.

So in effect:

```
title = business or name = business or statistics in default search field
```

Your second query:

```
title:statistics OR business) OR (name:statistics OR business)
```

.. searches for `statistics` in the `title` field, or `business` in the default search field, or `statistics` in the name field, or `business` (again) in the default search field. In effect:

```
title = statistics or name = statistics or business in the default search field
```

.. as you can see, these two queries are not the same. The `field:` prefix is only valid for the token that follows right behind it - not for those other tokens.

Using the edismax handler, I suggest you rewrite this to using the `qf` parameter instead (query fields), which tells Solr which fields to query. Your two examples can then be simplified to:

```
q=statistics business&qf=name title
```

.. search for `statistics` and `business` in the two fields named in the `qf` parameter. You can use `q.op=OR` to get hits where any of the terms are present (as in your example), or `q.op=AND` to get hits where both are present.

In that case `statistics business` and `business statistics` as the query will give you the same result.

If you want to use the explicit syntax (aka the Lucene syntax), you can use the form `field:(term1 OR term2)` - `title:(business OR statistics) OR name:(business OR statistics)` - but since you're already using the `edismax` handler, I recommend using the built-in support for more natural queries and using `qf` to say which fields to search. You can also use weights with `qf` to weigh hits in the two fields differently - `qf=name^3 title` will give three times the weigh to any hits in the `name` field.